# Jsp that calls a web service in domain

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat5.5

I want to write a .jsp (tomcat5.5) that calls a web service (IIS in domain). I get an HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized. It seems that in order to call the web service you have to be a domain user. I want to allow access to the jsp only to domain users. The request.getRemoteUser() in the jsp returns null but not the domain user that calls the jsp.

From a web browser I call the web service and it works fine.

I am a bit confused with this. Can someone tell me how can the issue be resolved?
Do i have to make tomcat make SSO?

Thank you for your time.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

 response.setContentType("text/html");      
 PrintWriter o = response.getWriter();      
 o.println("sstarting...");
 o.println("user.name ".concat(System.getProperty("user.name")));       
 o.println("request.getRemoteUser() ".concat(request.getRemoteUser()));


 try {
   GetUserRoles getUserRolesRequest = new GetUserRoles();
            getUserRolesRequest.setApplicationId(121);
            getUserRolesRequest.setUserName("user");

            GetUserRolesResponse getUserRolesResponse;


            ServiceStub stub =new ServiceStub() ;

                         stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED,"false");              
    getUserRolesResponse = stub.getUserRoles(getUserRolesRequest); //IT FAILS HERE 401
    String str =getUserRolesResponse.getGetUserRolesResult().toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block                  
            e.printStackTrace();            
            o.println(e.getMessage());          
        }


    }
```

Comment: Show us some code and then we will be in better position to help you.

Comment: OK i added the code to the original post but does this help you?

Comment: It seems I have to implement SSO on tomcat.